# save Image uri outside of its component - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, imagepicker

How to implement onChange and value props so that Image uri could be saved outside the component?
Using expo ImagePicker and React Native.

```
type PhotoComponentProps = {
    value: string | undefined;
    onChange: (value: string | undefined) => void;
};

export function PhotoComponent({value, onChange} : PhotoComponentProps) {
    const [pickedImage, setImage] = React.useState<string | null>(null);


const pickImage = async () => {
    const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
        allowsEditing: false,
        aspect: [4, 3],
        quality: 1,
    });

    if (!result.cancelled) {
        setImage(result.uri);
    }
};

function deleteImage() {
    setImage(() => null);
}

return (
            <View>
                <Button onPress={deleteImage} />
                <Button onPress={openCamera} />
                <Button onPress={pickImage} />
               {pickedImage && <Image source={{ uri: pickedImage }} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }}/> }
            </View>
);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replaced `pickedImage` with `value` and `setImage` with `onChange`

```
  type PhotoComponentProps = {
    value: string | undefined;
    onChange: (value: string | undefined) => void;
};

export function PhotoComponent({value, onChange} : PhotoComponentProps) {

const pickImage = async () => {
    const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
        allowsEditing: false,
        aspect: [4, 3],
        quality: 1,
    });

    if (!result.cancelled) {
        onChange(result.uri);
    }
};
  
return (
            <View>
                <Button onPress={openCamera} />
                <Button onPress={pickImage} />
               {value && <Image source={{ uri: value }} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }}/> }
            </View>
);
```

And from otside created a state and passed value

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState<string | undefined>(undefined);

<Photo onChange={setValue} value={value} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use a client-state solution if you want to raise your state to a upper level or app level.

I would recommend using [Jotai](https://jotai.org/) looking at your current problem.But if you want a rock solid solution which should be reusable on other occasions as well, then go for something like [redux](https://redux.js.org/).

Jotai is simple solution and light weight where as redux is much more complicated and involve boilerplate.